# how to localize the number of wordpress post views?

Tags: filters, views

I want to display post view in localize number. I add these function in function.php to do so

```
function make_bangla_number($str)
{
    $engNumber = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
    $bangNumber = array('à§§','à§¨','à§©','à§ª','à§«','à§¬','à§­','à§®','à§¯','à§¦');
    $converted = str_replace($engNumber, $bangNumber, $str);

    return $converted;
}

add_filter( 'the_views', 'make_bangla_number' );
```

But I am unable to show the number in localize. Whenever i call the_views it shows the english number. Any idea how to show the post view number in localize language?

For further info here is my post view function:

```
// function to count post views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// function to display number of post views.
function the_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' à¦¬à¦¾à¦°';
}
```

I have Bangla language pack installed and my site CHARSET is also UTF-8. Bangla language pack does all but can't convert the English number into bangla number. So I using that code. With that i can convert the date number in Bangla but unable to convert the views. So I am here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably, that you don't actually call the filter. WordPress does this not automatically for you.

If you want to create a custom filter you have to manually call [`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters), so that the added filters get executed:

```
function the_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        $count = 0;
    }

    // use apply_filters to call the filter
    return sprintf($count == 0 ? '%s View' : '%s Ã Â¦Â¬Ã Â¦Â¾Ã Â¦Â°', 
        apply_filters('the_views', $count));

    // better alternative: use the WordPress translation API:
    //return sprintf(_n('%s View', '%s Views', $count), 
        //apply_filters('the_views', $count));
}
```

I have modified the code a bit so the digit "0" gets also translated/converted. I have also added a suggestion at the end to use the WP translation API. There's a bit more effort required to translate it that way but it would bring some benefits (you could translate it to other languages without code-changes and the result would be proper pluralized).